# Front facing camera on iPhone preview mirrored

Tags: ios, swift, ios11, avcapturedevice

I am using working with swift on xcode 9.2 to code up a quick preview app for my ios 11. My issue is that when I deploy the following code snippet to start a video preview using my front camera the preview is mirrored. Is there a way to avoid this mirroring? Or maybe mirror it again so it normalizes?

```
guard let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: AVMediaType.video, position: .front) else {
    print ("Error: no video devices available")
    return false
}
```

Comment: Hey, I'm running into the same issue. Did you figure out a solution? Thanks!

Comment: Did you get any solution?